# Cannot remove composer root package dependency package

Tags: composer-php

I need to remove the package `http-interop/http-middleware` and replace it with `http-interop/http-server-middleware`.

It's not a defined package in my `composer.json` but from what I can see stems from `zendframework/zendframework`.

In any case, when I try to run `composer remove http-interop/http-middleware` it does not remove the package. Then, I get this when trying to run `composer require http-interop/http-server-middleware`

```
Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install http-interop/http-server-middleware 1.1.1
- don't install http-interop/http-server-middleware 1.1.0|remove http-interop/http-middleware 0.2.0
- don't install http-interop/http-server-middleware 1.1.0|don't install http-interop/http-middleware 0.2.0
- don't install http-interop/http-server-middleware 1.1.0|don't install http-interop/http-middleware 0.2.0
- Installation request for http-interop/http-server-middleware ^1.1 -> satisfiable by http-interop/http-server-middleware[1.1.0, 1.1.1].
- Installation request for http-interop/http-middleware (locked at 0.2.0) -> satisfiable by http-interop/http-middleware[0.2.0].
```

I really do not know what to do at this point.

Comment: Were you able to fix it? The accepted answer didn't work for me..

Answer (score 0):

If that is a package required by another package, you cannot remove it without removing that other package. In your case: you have to get rid of `zendframework/zendframework` first, but that is surely not what you want.

According to https://packagist.org/packages/http-interop/http-middleware/dependents?page=13, the dependency comes from multiple packages in the zendframework. They directly require `^0.4.1` of that package and `http-interop/http-server-middleware` contains a replace section. So, probably you get it working by **adding** `http-interop/http-server-middleware` first and remove `http-interop/http-middleware` afterwards?

Comment: Hi, the OP seems to have fixed the issue with your answer.. i.e. `adding http-interop/http-server-middleware first and remove http-interop/http-middleware afterwards`. I tried with adding `psr/http-server-middleware` or `http-interop/http-server-middleware` and then remove `http-interop/http-middleware`, but still I can't see it removed from composer.lock and I always get that deprecation warning.. I have also tried with `composer update http-interop/http-middleware` after removing it, but still no luck.. Am I missing something? Is there any other way?

Comment: I must have mistakingly accepted this answer. It did not work for me either.